# Can't send post request

Tags: reactjs, react-router, axios

I'm trying to send data in ReactJS with axios via a post request.
The problem is when I send data it appears in my url like this 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/Sessions/11?courses=2018-09-30' but I want it to go in my database.

My request is like this :

```
AddCourses (courses) {

axios.request({
method: 'post',
url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/sessions/${session_id}/courses`,
data: courses,
headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' , 'Accept': 
'application/json' , 'Authorization': `Bearer 
${authentication.getToken()}`}

 }).catch(err => console.log(err))
}

onSubmit (event) {
let session_id = this.props.match.params.id

const newCourses = {
 date: this.refs.date.value,
}
this.AddCourses(newCourses)
event.preventDefault(
this.props.history.push(`/Courses`),
)
}
```

And my props are defined like this in my router :

```
   <Route path="/Sessions" exact component={Sessions}/>
   <Route path="/Sessions/:id" exact render={props => 
   <GeekSessions{...props} /> }/>
```

In my component I have another post request and when I test it, I have the error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined'

I can't figure out these two problems. If you have any solutions this would be very cool.
Thank you guys.

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide some more code, e.g. where you define your props.

Comment: For me, the props are defined in my router when I do this `              <Route path="/Sessions/:id" exact render={props => <GeekSessions{...props} /> }/>
` with that, i can use the id of the session. I have an other component who is defined on the same process and i don't have problem for send a post request... And in my component I use this `    let session_id = this.props.match.params.id
` in a get request and it's work's that why i don't understand why in a quest based on same parameters, I have this problem

Comment: It would be helpful if you edited your post accordingly. Please add the additional code examples in your original post and format it so everybody can see it without reading the comments.